# How can I make aptitude show me the files that will be installed for a given package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, aptitude

On ubuntu I would like to know which files that will be installed when running `sudo aptitude install ruby-rvm`.

So first I do `sudo aptitude download ruby-rvm`. Now I can do `aptitude show ruby-rvm`, but **how can I get the list of files that will be installed during a `sudo aptitude install ruby-rvm`?** something like `dpkg -L ruby-rvm` if I had installed it, I just want to know it before I install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if aptitude can do such a thing. But you can use:

```
apt-file show package_name
```

It will show all files which this package will install. If you would like to list all files which package contains, you can do it like this:

```
apt-file list package_name
```

It will list all the files located inside a package. 

If you do not have installed apt-file then use:

```
apt-get install apt-file
```

and update the cache (it will take some time) by:

```
apt-file update
```

You can also to which package specific file belongs:

```
apt-file search file_name
```

You can also list files in a package on this website [List files in package](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents)
Or you can use `dpkg -L package_name` (but as you mentioned, it is working on already installed packages) as mentioned by @topdog.

Answer (score 0):

aptitude does not have the ability to show the files installed per package, use dpkg -L for that

Comment: `dpkg -L` requires the package to be installed. I was aksing for a solution prior to installing the package.